# Vector space sizes

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

$T:V \rightarrow V$ where $V$ is a finite dimensional real vector space

I can show that $\ker(T) \subseteq \ker(T^2) \subseteq \ker(T^3) \subseteq\cdots $

Prove there exists some $k$ such that $\ker(T^k)=\ker(T^{k+j}) $

$\forall j \geq 0 $

My plan: show there exists some $k$ such that $\ker(T^k)=\ker(T^{k+1}) $  I have already shown via rank-nullity and induction that if this is true the bit we are trying to prove will also be true. But I don't want to digress with that.

In order to show there exists some $k$ such that $\ker(T^k)=\ker(T^{k+1}) $

Assume there exists no such $k$

Then $\ker(T) \subset \ker(T^2) \subset \ker(T^3) \subset \cdots $ (strict subsets)

so the size of the set $\ker(T^n)$ is strictly increasing. I was hoping to reach some kind of contradiction because $\ker(T^n)$ is a subspace of $V$ -well it's a subset which is the main thing. So it cant keep increasing forever...
but then $V$ may not be a finite vector space so not really sure what to do...

**Question:** 
It makes no sense to say a vector space is finite does it?- it must be a set of infinite size- even if a vector space has a finite basis there infinitely many linear combinations you could take of the basis elements right?

Comment: Let $V$ be the vector space of polynomials and let $T$ be the formal derivative. Then no such $k$ exists.

Comment: A vector space _can_ be finite, but only if either (1) it has dimension $0$, or (2) it has finite dimension _and_ is defined over a finite field.

Comment: @Arcane1729 consider using `\ker` instead of `ker`. Also, you might like to know that $\subsetneq$ is given by `\subsetneq`.

Comment: I changed it to \ker.  That not only prevents italicization but also results in proper spacing in things like $a\ker b$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If $V$ is finite-dimensional, all subspaces are finite dimensional, and if  if a subspace $K_1$ is contained in the subspace $K_2$, and $\dim K_1=\dim K_2$, then $K_1=K_2$.

Comment: Ahhh! So $ker(T^n)=ker(T^{n+1})$  iff $dim ker(T^n)=dim ker(T^{n+1}) $                              We also have $dim U \leq dim V$  if $U$ is a subspace of $V$ Combining this if no such $k$ exists then $dim ker(T) < dim ker (T^2) < dim ker(T^3)... $ (stricly less than since none are equal) So the dimensions will keep increasing forever but V is finite dimensional. Contradiction. Youre a genius Bernard! Thank you!

Comment: I don't think it's really a contradiction: simply when $\dim V$  is attained (if it is) the sequence of kernels stabilises. In any case, it just come down to the fact that a non-decreasing bounded sequence of integers is eventually constant.

Answer (score 3):

A few things:

**Yes, a vector space can be finite:**
In particular, every finite-dimensional space over a finite field is finite.  The integers modulo any prime gives you a finite field.  The only finite vector spaces over infinite fields like $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$, however, are the trivial space $\{0\}$.

**Yes, a vector space can be infinite dimensional:**
Two classic examples are the space of polynomials and the space of infinite sequences.

**Your result will only hold for finite dimensional spaces:**
Consider the function on the space of infinite sequences given by
$$
(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots) \mapsto (x_2,x_3,x_4,\dots)
$$

**Yes, your result holds for all finite dimensional spaces $V$:**
In particular, it suffices to note that

- $\ker T^{j} \subseteq \ker T^{j+1}$
- $\ker T^j$ is always a subspace
- if $\ker T^k = \ker T^{k+1}$, then $\ker T^k = \ker T^{k+j}$ for all integers $j \geq 0$.

And of course, if $V$ is finite dimensional, $\dim \ker T^j \leq \dim V$.

Comment: How is $ker(T^{j+1}) \subseteq ker(T^{j})$ ?

Comment: @Arcane1729 whoops, had it backwards