# In the context of linear algebra, is it possible for a vector space or a subspace to have a finite number of elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

A vector space must satisfy closure under addition and multiplication. Sorry if this is obvious but does that mean that, assuming the normal rules of arithmetic and excluding the trivial examples like $V=\{0\}$  it is impossible for a vector space to have a finite number of elements? (since for every two elements $u,v \in V$ there must be another number $u+v \in V$)

Comment: Just work with a finite dimensional vector space over a finite field

Comment: This all depends on the field it is a vector space over. If the field is finite then yes, otherwise no.

Comment: An example of finite field is $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for prime $p$. Also, there are finite fields of order $p^n$ for any prime $p$ and integer $n\geq 1$.

Comment: Ah okay, but if the vector field is over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ it must have an infinite number of elements correct?

Comment: Yes, since it has to contain all scalar multiples of an element, and these are already infinitely many.

Comment: [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1408324/81360)

Comment: [Also related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1343523/81360)

Answer (score 0):

Such a vector space would have to be finite-dimensional, of course.

But every finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over a field $\Bbb k$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb k^{\oplus n}$ for some $n$. This means that $V$ has finitely many vectors if and only if $V$ is finite-dimensional and $\Bbb k$ is a [finite field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field).

For each prime $p$ and $n\geq0$ it is known that there is a unique field of order $p^n$. This classifies all possible vector spaces with finitely many vectors.